# Cannot read property of "undefined": POST request from React to Express

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, redux, axios

I have this controller to authenticate a user by their email and password

```
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Hit');
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  await User.findOne({ email }, async (err1, foundUser) => {
    if (err1) {
      next(err1);
    } else if (foundUser && (await foundUser.matchPasswords(password))) {
      res.json({
        _id: foundUser._id,
        name: foundUser.name,
        email: foundUser.email,
        token: generateWebToken(foundUser._id),
      });
    } else {
      res.status(401);
      next(new Error('Invalid credentials'));
    }
  });
});
```

where the mongoose instance method `matchPasswords` is defined as

```
userSchema.methods.matchPasswords = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(
    enteredPassword,
    this.password,
    (err, success) => {
      console.log(success);
      return success;
    }
  );
};
```

In the React frontend I have created an action creator `loginUser` like so

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      '/api/v1/users/login',
      { email, password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.message.data
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

However, when I try to login with the wrong credentials or the correct ones I receive this message in the screen and console `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`. Above that there is this error `main.js?attr=bsXXNSP9r2dL_fbuBOkoev2GjgusyPgY7MC7K-twziLtf_MItBzQdXJ4l_HgsPQw:2699 POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login 401 (Unauthorized)` which made me think maybe it's proxy error because my server is running on port 5000, but the `console.log('Hit');` inside the `authUser` controller is fired when I make the request, which means the request reaches the backend, but there is some uncaught error. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `error.response.data.message` != `error.response.message.data`

Comment: Stupid me! Thank you @DaveNewton